# Equations with Sinus. How to find equation solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I don't understand how to get a solution for sinus equation.

I have:

$$\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$$

\begin{align*}
x & = (-1)^k \cdot \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 180^\circ \cdot k, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
  & = (-1)^k \cdot 30^\circ + 180^\circ \cdot k, k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

Answer: $x = \ldots$

How to find x?

Comment: You can right-click on the equations, then click Show Math As TeX Commands to see how I typeset them.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you have done is correct. There is not a unique solution for that equation; recall for instance that $\sin(30^\circ)=\sin(150^\circ)=1/2$. The latter expression is the general solution of the equation. You could alternatively had noticed that
$$\sin(x)=1/2 \Longleftrightarrow \sin(x) = \sin(30^\circ) \Longleftrightarrow x = 30^\circ + 2k\pi \vee x = 150^\circ + 2k\pi,$$ for $k$ integer. It's equivalent but I think it's simpler.

Comment: You can produce $\sin(30^\circ)$ by typing \sin(30^\circ) in math mode.   You can produce $\Leftrightarrow$ by typing \Leftrightarrow in math mode.  You can produce $\Longleftrightarrow$ by typing \Longleftrightarrow in math mode.

Answer (score 2):

what you have $x = (-1)^k 30^\circ+180^\circ \cdot k$  is correct.

but can also be done the following way.
the solutions of $$\sin x = \frac 12$$  are $$x = \sin^{-1}(1/2) + k\cdot 360^\circ, 180 - \sin^{-1}(1/2) + k\cdot 360^\circ \\
x = 30^\circ + k\cdot 360^\circ, 150^\circ + k\cdot 360^\circ, \quad k \text{ any integer.} $$

Comment: You misread the question.  Commander Shepard (the OP) wrote $x = (-1)^k \cdot 30^\circ + 180^\circ \color{blue}{\cdot k, k \in \mathbb{Z}}$, which is equivalent to the answer you gave.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thanks. i overlooked that second $k.$  i edited the post accordingly.